# Is there a matrix that can change the position of an entry?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that I have a matrix A of size (n x n), and the entry in the i-th row and j-th column is 'a'.  Is there a matrix (also of size (n x n)) that I can multiply A by in order to in a sense "change" the position of a, so that the resulting matrix has in its k-th rown and l-th column the element 'a'?

In other words, I essentially want to be able to move a particular entry in the matrix to any other given position in the matrix.

Edit:  I am trying to use linear transformations, and no I don't care about what happens to the other entries of the matrix.

Comment: If the transformation is not linear, then there is no hope for just a matrix multiplication to suffice. Also, do you care what happens to the other entries of the matrix?

Comment: No. Label the columns of $v_1,...,v_n$ so that A=(v_1 ... v_n). If $B$ is another nxn matrix then $BA=(Bv_1 ... Bv_n)$. So, if one of the $v_k$ is all zeros then it will stay all zeros. On a positive note, if you allow two matrices B and C then you can do this so that $BAC$ does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False, and this can be seen in the 2x2 case. Left multiplication gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & a
\end{pmatrix}$$
and right multiplication gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but to achieve
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
a & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
would require conjugation (check for yourself).